# How to trigger command after build?

Tags: deployment, triggers, maven

Is there a way for maven to trigger system command after successful or unsuccessful build?
Right now I'm using external script to run `mvn package`, but I would like this feature integrated with maven process.

Comment: You know that mvn package include all previous life-cycle phases...so what did you run before the mvn package ?

Comment: I'm using only `mvn package`, external script is used to for example copy files to server.

Comment: External server means production/test?

Comment: Both, there are few different scripts, now I would like to rethink and rebuild this system.

Comment: If you like to go to production mvn package is wrong. You should use mvn release:prepare release:perform and then use the artifacts which are stored in the Repo Manager.

Comment: OK, thanks, what about copying packaged jar to test servers?

Comment: Why would you like to copy jar files? Aren't you using war/ear files ? Furthermore you can use the maven-wagon-plugin to transfer files to a server...but this not the focus of Maven. Better write a command line app with the Help of Aether Lib (Access Maven Repositories) ...

Comment: This is simple jar written in Java SE, but it's running on servers. I'll check out this plugin you mentioned.

Comment: On which kind of server?

Comment: Linux - Debian. But it's a standalone app that's doing some calculations and produces output files.

Comment: You mean the simple jar you mentioned is a command line app ?

Comment: Why don't you use 'mvn deploy' and use Maven deploy plugin to copy the jars using ftp? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

Comment: Yes, it's a command line app.

Answer (score 0):

Maven supports pre and post scripts. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293408/can-i-instruct-maven-to-use-another-jdk-other-than-the-one-specified-at-java-hom). In your case it would be mavenrc_post.bat

> You can easily do that by creating a file at /etc/mavenrc or
>   ~/.mavenrc (Linux) or %HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat (Windows) Maven executes
>   those on startup if they exist unless you've defined a variable named
>   MAVEN_SKIP_RC.