# How to instruct Maven to use JDK other than the one specified at JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, maven

Currently my `JAVA_HOME` is set to a JDK that is 1.4.2.

To run Maven 3, I would need 1.5 and above.

Is there any way to instruct my Maven installation to use another JDK that is installed other than changing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: Can't you explicitly overwrite JAVA_HOME in the script you use to start maven? You need JAVA_HOME for anything else than maven?

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME is set to 1.4.2 for my development environment, namely for BEA 8.1 server and alot of things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's pretty much the way to do it. I assume you mean you don't want to change your global JAVA_HOME. That's fine. You just need to set a different JAVA_HOME for Maven. You can easily do that by creating a file at `/etc/mavenrc` or `~/.mavenrc` (Linux) or `%HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat` (Windows) with the appropriate JAVA_HOME defined in it. Maven executes those on startup if they exist unless you've defined a variable named `MAVEN_SKIP_RC`. You could also modify the Maven startup scripts directly, but there's no good reason for that since it gives you these nice hooks.

Comment: I am not quite getting there, do i create a bat called mavenrc_pre.bat? How should that file look like?

Comment: Yes. Create mavenrc_pre.bat in your home directory, and put `JAVA_HOME=<your jdk 6 home>` in it. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

STEP 1:

Find apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat, then find and replace JAVA_HOME to JAVA_HOME_MVN.
Note: Before this, make a backup of mvn.bat

STEP 2:

Create a new environment variable called JAVA_HOME_MVN and point it to the bin of whichever jdk you want to use.

Comment: This is a good attempt. Working fine for me. My JAVA_HOME_MVN environment variable points to Jdk 11 and my regular JAVA_HOME has Jdk 8