# run configuration to build maven project and deploy to tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am writing a java program using maven and running on a tomcat 9 server.
I created a run configuration to build the project, but I was wondering if there is a way to modify the configuration to build the project and also deploy it to my server.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For small project you need e little workaround here:

- First create e post script for maven (`mavenrc_post.bat`for windows) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649568/how-to-trigger-command-after-build)
- In this script you have to move build files via ssh, and restart tomcat(you need to configure ssh on server).

For large projects you need software for automation like:

- Ansible Automation platform
- Docker Containers
- Azure Devops etc.